# I have a freezing issue with my JavaScript dice roller

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a `JavaScript` based **dice roller** for use in Warhammer 40K. The script seems to work properly, but sometimes it freezes and takes a long time to get a result after pressing the button several times.

In the script you can make various settings, such as the number of cubes, the number of sides of a cube, a threshold value that the user wants to reach, exceed or fall below and an optional repeat function.
There is also a "Wrath Die" rolled, which is a mechanic in the Wrath & Glory TTRPG. This die is separate and does not contribute to the main roll.

I think it might have something to do with the accumulating event listeners on the "Roll" button every time it is clicked. But I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

**This is the code I use in my HTML page:**

```js
var diceRollHistory = [];

function rollDice() {

    var numDice = parseInt(document.getElementById("numDice").value);
    var numSides = parseInt(document.getElementById("numSides").value);
    var greaterLessThan = document.getElementById("greaterLessThan").value;
    var threshold = parseInt(document.getElementById("threshold").value);
    var reroll = parseInt(document.getElementById("reroll").value);

    var diceRolls = [];
    var total = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < numDice; i++) {
        var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * numSides) + 1;
        diceRolls.push(roll);
        total += roll;
    }

    if (!isNaN(reroll)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < diceRolls.length; i++) {
            if (diceRolls[i] === reroll) {
                var newRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * numSides) + 1;
                diceRolls[i] = diceRolls[i] + " Rerolled: " + newRoll;
                total -= reroll;
                total += newRoll;
            }
        }
    }

    diceRollHistory.unshift(diceRolls);
    var output = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < diceRolls.length; i++) {
        output += "Roll " + (i + 1) + ": " + diceRolls[i] + "<br>";
    }

    output += "Total: " + total + "<br>";
    var count = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < diceRolls.length; i++) {
        if (greaterLessThan === ">=" 
            && (diceRolls[i] >= threshold 
            || (diceRolls[i].includes("Rerolled") 
            && parseInt(diceRolls[i].split(":")[1]) >= threshold))
        ) {
            count++;
        } else if (
            greaterLessThan === "<=" 
            && (diceRolls[i] <= threshold 
            || (diceRolls[i].includes("Rerolled") 
            && parseInt(diceRolls[i].split(":")[1]) <= threshold))
        ) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    output += "Dice rolls that are " + greaterLessThan + " " + threshold + ": " + count + "<br>";

    var separateRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    output += "Wrath Dice: " + separateRoll;

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
    displayHistory();
}

function displayHistory() {

    var historyOutput = "<h2>Dice Roll History</h2><h3>Latest Roll:</h3>";

    for (var i = 0; i < diceRollHistory.length; i++) {
        historyOutput += "<p>";
        var diceRolls = diceRollHistory[i];

        for (var j = 0; j < diceRolls.length; j++) {
            historyOutput += "Roll " + (j + 1) + ": " + diceRolls[j] + "<br>";
        }
        
        historyOutput += "</p>";
    }

    document.getElementById("history").innerHTML = historyOutput;
}
```

```html
<label for="numDice">Dice amount:</label><br>
<input type="number" id="numDice" name="numDice" min="1" required><br>

<label for="numSides">Dice sides:</label><br>
<input type="number" id="numSides" name="numSides" min="1" required><br>

<label for="greaterLessThan">Greater or less than:</label>
<select id="greaterLessThan" name="greaterLessThan">
  <option value=">=">>=</option>
  <option value="<="><=</option>
</select><br>

<label for="threshold">Threshold:</label><br>
<input type="number" id="threshold" name="threshold" min="1" required><br>

<label for="reroll">Reroll:</label><br>
<input type="number" id="reroll" name="reroll" min="1"><br>

<button onclick="rollDice()">Roll</button>

<div id="output"></div>

<div id="history"></div>
```

Comment: Just for the record, if threshold > 2 the script may break.